# Consequences of changing Ukrainian for Russian Citizenship for an Expat living in France

Tags: france, citizenship, resident-permit, russia, ukraine

I am an Ukrainian Citizen married to a French citizen and living in France of a French Residence Permit for as yet limited validity, obtained based on my marriage certificate + Spouse Visa as granted on my Ukrainian passport. I have real estate property and family in Crimea. In principle I must apply for Russian Citzenship before 31/12/14.

Questions:

1. If I would apply for Russian Citizenship, would this affect my Residence Permit situation in France
2. If I don't apply for Russian Citizenship in the Crimea, would this expose me to Russian (Criminal) Administrative Charges ? or loss of Crimean Property Rights ?
3. Would dual -eventual- French and/or Ukrainian/Russian citizenship be a criminal offense in under Russian Law ?

Comment: why "*must*" you apply? Are foreigners not allowed to have property in Russia?

Answer (score 2):

1. No, you might as well be a citizen of Timbuktu as far as France is concerned. Just make sure to notify the authority which issued your Residency Permit of this change.
2. As of 2016 there have been no such reports
3. No, dual citizenship is allowed in Russia. France doesn't care as long as you don't apply for French citizenship.

Comment: Why “as long as you don't apply for French citizenship”? France doesn't really care even then.

Comment: @Gala because then France would like to see a paper confirming the other country won't mind you becoming a dual citizen, which might cause issues outside the scope of the question

Comment: Is that so? I am not aware of any such requirement. Matter of fact, someone in my family became French last year. She was previously a citizen of the country which might have the most restrictive citizenship law on earth (the DRC, where the constitution simply states “The Congolese citizenship cannot be held at the same time than any other” *without any exception*) and this never came up AFAIK.

Answer (score -1):

You would likely have to reapply for visa based on your new passport unless you obtained French citizenship (to which you are likely entitled on marital merit).

So in my personal opinion:

1. changing nationality would void your visa.
2. non compliance with Russian directives is likely to result in undesirable outcomes.

In any case it is worth enquiring about it with the [Russian ambassy/consulate](http://www.russianembassy.ru/en/embassies/france). They might even facilitate visa transition.

Comment: Ukraine doesn't allow dual citizenship